# Getting quantity of issues through github.api

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api

My task is to get the number of open issues using github.api. Unfortunately, when I parsing any repositories, I get the same number - 30.

```
import requests


r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues')
count = 0
for item in r.json():
    if item['state'] == 'open':
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Is there any way to get a real quantity of issues?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation about the `Link` response header, also you can pass the `state` or `filter`s.

- https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/
- https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

You'll have to page through.

```
http://.../issues?page=1&state=open
http://.../issues?page=2&state=open
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/issues/` endpoint is paginated: it means that you will have to iterate through several pages to get all the issues.

- https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues?page=1
- https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues?page=2
- ...

But there is a better way to get what you want. The `GET /repos/:owner/:repo` directly gives the number of open issues on a repository.

For instance, on https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc, you can see:

```
  "open_issues_count": 1052,
```

Click [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) to have a look at the documentation for this endpoint.